# Let's see if we can reduce the number of Unanswered Questions before New Year!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, winterbash

We currently have over [3500 unanswered questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on Security.SE.

Whether or not you are after some hats for [Winterbash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/), or just want to find some posts you could provide answers to and gain rep, please go and have a look at them. There are bound to be some in there in your field of expertise, or that you can research.

I'd be delighted if we could get it down to 2000 before the end of Winterbash - even if it means it's not just [Anders](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/98538/anders) and [forest](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/165253/forest) ahead of me on the [Security Winterbash leaderboard!](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: So basically, start upvoting answers?

Comment: well - if there are good answers that are not yet upvoted, yes :-)

Comment: I think we're *losing* ground instead - answerers are off with family, but the askers are still here!

Comment: @Xiong - the numbers are actually coming down a wee bit, so the community is doing well despite many being away for holidays.

Comment: While I encourage positive action, this should not be used as an excuse to close questions just because they are difficult to answer.

Comment: Hats are gone, and so are 500 unanswered questions. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Well - the results are in.

We answered or closed around 500 unanswered questions...

And we still have around 3500 unanswered questions :-)

SO this shows that as a community, even over the Christmas break, we can still find old or unloved questions and add an answer, or upvote an existing answer, or in many cases improve an existing answer so it gets upvotes.

Nice work to all who helped.

Comment: When I go to the [unanswered page](https://security.stackexchange.com/unanswered) it says 2,948 question to the right, not 3 500. Anyway, I agree, good job!

Comment: Interesting - there must be a caching issue. I still see just over 3500. I like your number better.

Comment: Lets hope mine is the correct one!